# What is it called when I see another person in the mirror when there is only me

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes when I look into a mirror, I see a vague vision of a woman standing behind me and when I turn my head she's gone: there is no one.

I don't think the word is *haunted* because I don't believe in ghosts. I am not superstitious. I'm a physic undergraduate, I work on string theory.

*Then I remember it only occurs in lucid dreams.* And I now have spectrophobia.

Comment: You are being *schizophrenic*. And it seems to be serious. Either that or some woman in your home is playing games with you.

Comment: @Mohit Sounds horrible.

Comment: And I don't think you can call it a *phenomenon*. It happens only in your head. It is an *hallucination*.

Comment: @Mohit What if most people can't see them because they emit a different wavelength of electromagnetic wave and they come from another dimensions?

Comment: what is the antonym of vampire?

Comment: Can't think of a suitable SE site for this. Perhaps skepticsSE?

Comment: @cartogram If you could detect the electromagnetic radiation reflected in a mirror, you would be able to detect it looking at the object itself. Sorry, but this is a hallucination.

Comment: Working on a unified theory of physics of the universe and having weird misconceptions about fundamentals like wavelengths of light reflected from the mirror? tsk, tsk.

Comment: RE: "What if most people can't see them because they emit a different wavelength of electromagnetic wave and they come from another dimension?" To that I'd say, _you're_ the String Theorist; I'd expect you'd be the one to answer that question.

Comment: (Question was closed while I was working on this answer...) So working in String Theory is a talisman that somehow ensures against madness? Or that a belief 26 dimensions (to account for bosons) somehow nullifies a belief in ghosts? Couldn't your apparition be a *Boltzmann brain* phenomenon? (https://www.nytimes.com/2008/01/15/science/15brain.html?_r=0)

Comment: @rajah9 Not yet a talisman. Just an insane person in a superposition of accepting the truth that he is insane and denying it with M-theory that describes the 11 dimensions of the universe. Probably a new type of brain disorder similar to the [Anton–Babinski syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anton%E2%80%93Babinski_syndrome).

Comment: @J.R. Well, consider that a string theorist's sense of humor.

Comment: @SF. Certain types of surface can cause photon to be bounced off in an entirely different energy state (wavelength changes) and thus resulting in a different color detected by the eyes and, together with other photons, forming "images" as they're being interpreted by the brain. But well, consider the twisted wavelength by a supernatural ghosty mirror a physicist's intention to be mocked.

Comment: It looks as if nobody has mentioned *[pareidolia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia)*.

Comment: Unless you happened to chant Bloody Mary 13 times, consider the words **psychomanteum** and **mirror scrying**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Barring any explanation that depends upon a *phenomenon* outside of your own mind, the remaining explanation of the *epiphenomenon* is that it is a mild *hallucination*.

(We might be tempted to call this a "mirror hallucination", however that term is already used to refer to a hallucination where we see ourselves somewhere other than in a mirror, so is probably best avoided).

Dr. Oliver Sacks argues in his recent book, *Hallucinations*, that hallucinations are more common than often supposed, because they are under-reported due to stigma or fear of being considered as having a serious mental condition. This under-reporting in turn adds to the misconception that hallucinations only happen with serious mental conditions (or heavy intoxication), and so on, in a cycle that maintains this under-reporting. According to Sacks, having mild hallucinations need not be particularly troublesome.

However, it remains that hallucinations can indeed be caused by psychological or neurological complaints, so if the experience has only begun recently, or if it increases, it could well be worth seeking medical advice.

Answer (score 4):

If you believe it to be somewhat real, the word would be "apparition", if you think your mind is playing tricks on you, "hallucination" should do it.

Instead of asking for a label or a comfortable/convenient explanation, you should probably remove your assumptions and investigate:

Can you reproduce the phenomenon? Is there any pattern to it? Does it occur at a specific time of the day or at random? After eating a specific type of food? Does the woman always look the same? Is it always in the same mirror or does it happen with other mirrors? Do you have other, similar experiences? Have you had a recent head injury? Headaches? Does it happen only when you are tired? Are you sleeping enough? Are you taking any drugs (incl. prescription drugs)? ...

Pull the strings and get to the bottom of it. If you're lucky, it's just a dirty mirror and a case of not sleeping enough.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the term *Delusion* maybe, because what you see is the "projection" of your mind (but only when you look in the mirror).